# How to get old plasterboard wall ready for paint

Tags: drywall, painting, plaster, primer, wallpaper

there was multiple layers of painted wallpaper in a bedroom.

I've removed all the wallpaper and sanded the walls a small amount to get rid of residue and flaky plasterboard.

The plasterboard paper is torn in many places so i assume the walls need to be sealed with something before they can be skimmed.

After research it seems zinsser bin might need to cover all the walls and then possibly using bonding plaster as a skim coat.

I've read about using green grit as well but not sure what process to actually follow.

The walls are not plastered, they have some type of white primer or paint on them, can't see any taped joints either, all the patches are probably torn paper from the wallpaper removal

First time at this so all help appreciated

Please tell me a process to get these walls ready to paint

[image: example eall]

Answer (score 1):

My instinct is to apply a "skim coat" of plaster to even out the surface. Then prime and paint. Note that it may take several cycles of sanding and skim coating before you have a surface you're happy with, depending on skill and patience.

Answer (score 0):

First, drywall compound will stick to darn near everything. However, to help it along and to seal torn paper roll on a sealer.  I like [Bulls Eye 1-2-3](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Zinsser-Bulls-Eye-1-2-3-Interior-Exterior-Multi-Purpose-Water-Based-Wall-and-Ceiling-Primer-Actual-Net-Contents-128-fl-oz/3439970?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-pnt-_-ggl-_-LIA_PNT_117_Paint-and-Primers-_-3439970-_-local-_-0-_-0&gclid=Cj0KCQjw8NilBhDOARIsAHzpbLB7sdowF2Vp_oDRhI41IlG7a6egzV3_svW8mf_hl6_W1_rf-pzutuMaAge5EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)  But most any pre paint sealer will work.

Next fill in any deep gouges with drywall compound. Smooth as best a possible.

If you want smooth walls there is only one way.
Skim coat and sand. Skim again and sand.  Repeat until you are satisfied.
But understand even after you are done and primed and painted you may find areas the are wavy or have a slight hump or ridge.

To get a really smooth wall you need to call in a professional.  Someone that does that work on a daily basis. They have the experience to get a wall smooth.

```
                        **OR
```

You can seal and fill in the gouges. Wipe the edges with a damp sponge to knock down the hard edges.  Use the same type of sponge used to clean grout.

Then spray a texture on the walls. Orange-peel can be very light or heavier.
Here is and example....[image]

Knockdown, requires you spray it on then very lightly smooth it down with a wide taping  or knock down knife.

An example here...[image]

After the texture dries in a day, you can paint.

It's your choice. Whatever you choose, good luck

Answer (score 0):

It may be faster/easier to apply new, clean, smooth 1/4" drywall over the scarred mess and only have new joints to tape, than it will be to fill that mess until it's smooth.

Alternatively (but the time savings would have been better without going through the stripping process) rip the existing drywall off, do anything that needs doing in the walls (insulation or wiring upgrades, for example) and apply new drywall.